# Rspec passes class method but fails instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm trying to write a failing Rspec test. The actual test is associated with much longer code, but I narrowed down the problem to the class method it's testing.

Here's the test in Rspec:

```
context "For '.CASH.' as a stock" do
  let!(:cash) { FactoryGirl.create(:stock, symbol: '.CASH.', name: 'cash', status: 'Available') }

  describe "When update_stock runs on it" do
    it "should still have an 'Available' status" do
      # status should be 'Error' and test should fail
      Stock.change_to_error
      expect(cash.status).to eq('Available')
    end
  end
end
```

This is testing a model class method in Stock.rb:

```
def self.change_to_error
  self.all.each do |stock|
    stock.status = "Error"
    stock.save
  end
end
```

For some reason, this passes. However, if I changed it to use an instance method, it will fail like it should:

If stock_spec.rb changed to instance method:

```
context "For '.CASH.' as a stock" do
let!(:cash) { FactoryGirl.create(:stock, symbol: '.CASH.', name: 'cash', status: 'Available') }

  describe "When update_stock runs on it" do
    it "should still have an 'Available' status" do
        # status should be 'Error' and test should fail
        cash.change_to_error
        expect(cash.status).to eq('Available')
    end
  end
end
```

And if stock.rb class method turned into an instance method:

```
def change_to_error
  self.status = 'Error'
  self.save
end
```

This would pass. Unfortunately, I have to use a class method instead of an instance method because I want to update all stocks in the DB. "Change_to_error" methods are just there to figure out the problem. Does anyone know why it passes as a class method when it should fail? But it fails correctly when it's using an instance method?

Effectively, what is happening is that the class method does not change the status attribute of 'cash', but the instance method does. I don't know why that is happening.

FYI, I'm using rspec-rails

Comment: Can you try changing `stock.save` to `stock.save!`? If something is wrong, this will raise an exception.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't help. Other ideas?

Comment: Try using `Stock.find_each { |stock| stock.update_column(:status, 'Error') }`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I can see from logs that it does update with 'Error' as status but the spec still sees it as 'Available'

Comment: Ah! In addition to my last comment, change `let!` to `let` now, or use `stock.reload` before `expect`.

Comment: @31piy is right on with this. My rule of thumb is that if I'm not checking the boolean result of `save` and doing something with it, I should use `save!` so that an exception is raised.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Need to put 'cash.reload' after 'Stock.change_to_error' and before the expect line.

When using `let!` the object is created before the test. Updating the underlying data outside the object causes the instance to be outdated. Calling `reload` on it forces ActiveRecord to refresh it from the database.

---

When you use `let`, RSpec does not call the block until the first time you reference the attribute, in this case, `cash`. So in your first example, you're running `change_to_error` on no records at all and then checking the status on `cash`, a record that gets created on the line with `expect`. In your second example, the `cash` object is created, then changed to an error. I'd recommend tailing your log to confirm this (`tail -f log/test.log`)

If you change to `let!`, RSpec will create the object before every example is run. Another alternative is to reference `cash` in your example before calling `change_to_error` on all records that are created.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Even if I use a before loop and use an instance variable of @cash instead of let(:cash), it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: While that didn't solve the problem, I do realize that your observation is correct in the code that I provided above.

Comment: Try reloading `cash` before checking the status. Now that you're using let!, the model is created, your class method changes underlying models, but your `cash` instance may still have the cached value. Try `cash.reload!` then check the status.

Comment: Yes!!!! That worked!!! Thank you so much! I spent 4 hours trying to figure out what was wrong. Thanks!